# KORE Users - what are your favorite soundpacks/-FX? what's your workflow?

Tags: sound-design, effects, workflow

just interested because I'm planning to maybe get another soundpack since I was quite astonished by the quality of "Acoustic Refractions". I use those quite a lot as a source of inspiration.

what's your workflow when you go about designing sounds or soundscapes with KORE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard good stuff about all of Jeremiah Savage's KORE packs, though I don't own any.

I use KORE mostly for designing my own stuff from scratch. It's just a super clean way to be able to layer multiple instances of any combination of instruments, from any number of software makers, into a single preset that can be tagged and recalled later in a snap.

I will typically run KORE as an AU inside Live, Logic or AudioMulch for capturing my audio. Another neat thing which comes in surprisingly handy is the built-in step sequencer and arps. I keep a template preset with a series of C's and F#'s for when I want to generate a quick multisample set. I grab the audio in one shot, which gets dumped to AudioFinder, which splits it up for me, does pitch detection and names them automagically. Very helpful.

Mostly I just really love being able to have a single database for all of my instrument/fx patches. Well almost, it can't save the native proprietary devices from the likes of Logic, Live or 'Mulch - but you can get around that to a degree in some of them with saving channel strips etc.

Anyway, thumbs-up for KORE. Turned out to be a great investment and just kind of gets out of my way and helps me keep busy.

Comment: @theodorejordan I also love KORE for its ability to quickly try some layering inside its own VST shell on multiple source/fx channels. HOWEVER - this seems to get in the way of most DAW's own multitrack layout.. how do you deal with that? MIDI channel routing? seems a bit clunky, don't it?

Comment: @Julian Not sure I follow. I haven't really explored running it multitimbrally(sp?). Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hi, I usually improvise while recording in Ableton Live on my laptop. I keep on playing and just going with the flow until I have made 15-30 minutes of sound. Afterwards I export the recordings as files, which I then import into my Protools rig.

Then I cut it, layer it, pitch it, audiosuite it, add library fx, mix it, to the picture in Protools.